# Large image and ad unit above the fold on mobile site

Tags: google, google-adsense, images, content

(A.T.F. stands for Above The Fold, in case anyone is confused.)

I read the following on google:

> Is placing a 300x250 ad unit on top of a high-end mobile optimized page considered a policy violation?
>
> Yes, this would be considered a policy violation as it falls under our ad placement policies for site layout that pushes content below the fold. This implementation would take up too much space on a mobile optimized site's first view screen with ads and provides a poor experience to users. Always try to think of the users experience on your site - this will help ensure that users continue to visit.

Google shows the following as an example of bad ad placement:

[image: Bad placement example]

Currently my layout is this for pictures in landscape mode such as the picture shown, and I formatted the screen to match that of google's mobile device:

[image: Sample]

My ad unit is just below the fold and was even farther down below the fold yesterday, but I moved it up a bit because I feel I'll make a better income.

Problem is I'm still confused. How would adsense treat that ever-so-important photo above the fold? Does it treat it as nothing more than a null character?

If so, then is there a way I can apply to google to have my images above the fold and make money, because it would be a pain to shove all the text above the fold and make users scroll every time to pass the advertisement and to see the picture.

On the desktop version of my site I'm able to make money because I have text above, beside and below the ad unit but here, having text beside the ad unit isn't an option for most devices, especially for my mobile site when I set the viewport scale to 1 to eliminate side-scrolling.

So what is the best way to arrange my mobile page to make more money yet still satisfy the users? adsense loves only text, users love the big picture above the fold, and I'm making $0.

Comment: I thought ATF stood for Alcohol, Tobacco, and FIrearms all of which I am solidly in favor of. In fact, it is a nice warm sunny day...

Comment: I have to agree that is is a balancing act that may be seemingly impossible sometimes. I am not sure how to advise, you. Sorry. But if you get too frustrated, there is always the ATF I know... ;-) Good day for it! Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

> How would adsense treat that ever-so-important photo above the fold? Does it treat it as nothing more than a null character?

no, your image above the fold has its own physical size, namely the height, which Google can recognize. Google will be able to recognize the trick too, if you would try to set something like `img {height:0;}` to push the ad block higher. So don't worry - Big Brother is seeing your image.